# Orchard cms adding current widget types to custom module migration

Tags: orchardcms

I'm sure this must have been asked before. but I've been unable to find anything helpful.

I want to create some widgets (existing widget types, a menu, a projection), as part of a custom module install. aslo some queries and Projection pages.

as well as a new menu (orchard 1.5.1), I figured out the menu part form the code in the setup module

...

```
    // create a project menu
    var projectMenu = _menuService.Create("new Menu");

    // assign the project items to all current menu items
    foreach (var menuItem in _menuService.Get().Where(x => x.ContentItem.ContentType == "Project"))
    {
        // if they don't have a position or a text, then they are not displayed
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(menuItem.MenuPosition) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(menuItem.MenuText))
    {
       continue;
    }
    menuItem.Menu = projectMenu.ContentItem;
```

Can I include something in my migration to add the widgets and projections ?

I've been looking at the Orchard Recipe module, and see there is code there for executing commands to set up widgets. But I'm not sure how best to tap into this...

Creating an instance of recipe manages and executing a whole recipe seem a bit convoluted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some quite useful seemingly undocumented services all over the place you can use.

With the following constructor

```
public class MigrationProjectType : DataMigrationImpl 
    {
        private readonly IMenuService _menuService;
        private readonly IContentManager _contentManager;
        private readonly IQueryService _queryService;
        private readonly IWidgetsService _widgetsService;

        public MigrationProjectType(IMenuService menuService, IContentManager contentManager,  IQueryService queryService, IWidgetsService widgetsService)
        {
            _menuService = menuService;
            _contentManager = contentManager;
            _queryService = queryService;
            _widgetsService = widgetsService;
        }
...
}
```

Auto fac will take care of instantiating the services

then

```
public int UpdateFrom2()
        {
            // create a project menu
            var projectMenu = _menuService.Create("Projects Menu");

            // assign the project items to all current menu items
            foreach (var menuItem in _menuService.Get().Where(x => x.ContentItem.ContentType == "Project"))
            {
                // if they don't have a position or a text, then they are not displayed
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(menuItem.MenuPosition) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(menuItem.MenuText))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                menuItem.Menu = projectMenu.ContentItem;
            }

            // create layer part 
            _widgetsService.CreateLayer("SideBar", "desc", "url(\"~\")");

            var defaultLayer = _widgetsService.GetLayers().First(x => x.Name == "Default");

            var widget =  _widgetsService.CreateWidget(defaultLayer.Id, "MenuWidget", "Projects Menu", "2", "Navigation");

            var menuWidget = widget.As<MenuWidgetPart>();
            menuWidget.Record.Menu = projectMenu.ContentItem.Record;

            _contentManager.Publish(menuWidget.ContentItem);

            return 3;
        }
```

there is a similar service for Queries, but I'm stil not sure how to add filters to queries, for projections...

UPDATE

heres how you can add a query and filter

```
public int UpdateFrom7()
        {


            // create a project menu
            var projectMenu = _queryService.CreateQuery("My projects 3");

            var form = new Form { ContentTypes = "Project" };
            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(form.GetType());
            StringWriter sww = new StringWriter();
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww);
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, form);
            var state = sww.ToString();


            projectMenu.FilterGroups[0].Filters.Add(new FilterRecord
            {
                Category = "Content",
                Description = "My filter",
                Position = 0,
                State = state,
                Type = "ContentTypes"
            });

            _contentManager.Publish(projectMenu.ContentItem);


            return 8;
        }

[Serializable]
    public class Form
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ContentTypes { get; set; }

    }
```